# VideoToolbox hardware encoded I frame not clear on Intel Mac

Tags: macos, x86-64, intel, hardware-acceleration, video-toolbox

When I captured video from camera on Intel Mac, used VideoToolbox to hardware encode raw pixel buffers to H.264 codec slices, I found that the VideoToolbox encoded I frame not clear, causing it looks like blurs every serveral seconds. Below are properties setted:

```
self.bitrate = 1000000;
self.frameRate = 20;
int interval_second = 2;
int interval_second = 2;
NSDictionary *compressionProperties = @{
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel: (id)kVTProfileLevel_H264_High_AutoLevel,
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime: @YES,
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering: @NO,
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_H264EntropyMode: (id)kVTH264EntropyMode_CABAC,
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_PixelTransferProperties: @{
        (id)kVTPixelTransferPropertyKey_ScalingMode: (id)kVTScalingMode_Trim,
    },
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate: @(self.bitrate),
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate: @(self.frameRate),
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval: @(self.frameRate * interval_second),
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameIntervalDuration: @(interval_second),
    (id)kVTCompressionPropertyKey_DataRateLimits: @[@(self.bitrate / 8), @1.0],
};
result = VTSessionSetProperties(self.compressionSession, (CFDictionaryRef)compressionProperties);
if (result != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"VTSessionSetProperties failed: %d", (int)result);
    return;
} else {
    NSLog(@"VTSessionSetProperties succeeded");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are very strange compression settings. Do you really need short GOP and very strict data rate limits?
I very much suspect you just copied some code off the internet without having any idea what it does. If it's the case, just set interval_second = 300 and remove kVTCompressionPropertyKey_DataRateLimits completely